# GitlabAPI PUT approval_rules can't update group_ids

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to update the `group_ids` of specific approval rule in a project using the **PUT** API `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:proj/approval_rules/:ruleId`

using this call : `curl -s --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" --data 'name=Approval_ALL_GLs_experts' --data 'approvals_required=1' --data "group_ids[]=:groupId" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/:proj/approval_rules/xxx"`

The problem is that i'm getting the following response: `{"id":xxx,"name":"Approval_ALL_GLs_experts","rule_type":"regular","eligible_approvers":[],"approvals_required":1,"users":[],"groups":[],"contains_hidden_groups":false,"protected_branches":[]}`

My observation is that it's **not working** when I'm using a token of an owner of the *proj* but this user **is not** part of the *groupId*.
Using a token of an owner which is part of the *groupId* will do the work and update it correctly.